# Civi Events : New event issue

Tags: civievent

We have an issue when we want to create a Civi Event.

CiviCRM version : 5.54.1

WordPress version : 6.1

When we click on New CiviEvent, we have this display :
[image]

I found no log information about this issue in /civicrm/ConfigAndLog file

Do you have an idea regarding this issue ?